# Panasonic scanner is inserting data in edittext if any edit text is focused

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, barcode-scanner

I am using Toughpad for scanning from Panasonic, when i am scanning barcode, data is getting inserted in to edit text. How to prevent this.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Where do you want data to go?  Generally scanners like this act as keyboard interfaces, and will insert data into any control that has focus and accepts text.  If you want to change this behavior read the manual on how to configure the scanner

Comment: @Jason thanks for your reply.   I have implemented panasonic scanner, when ever scanner is scanned the data will come to onRead method. with this data from background will do some operations. Up to this evcerything is working properly. But if any edittext is existing in screen the scanned data is inserting in that control. i dont want to show this data to end user.

Comment: "If you want to change this behavior read the manual on how to configure the scanner"

Answer (score 0):

You should ask Panasonic. But from what you've written and from my experience with different scanners, I would say that you can't. This scanner seems to work as keyboard (it emulates keyboard), so the scanned contet will be automatically put into focused control. So the only thing you could do something with events like OnKeyDown/Up/Pressed.

Or maybe there is some other way to tell this scanner to work on COM Port, but I doubt it.

Comment: for Zebra and honey well its not inserting in to edit text, its happening for Panasonic only.